# jsTree scrolls back to top when selecting a scrolled element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

The project I'm working on was really improved when we found jsTree, but we deal with a big database, so the necessity to scroll is primary. The problem is that when selecting an element to I had to scroll to see, the tree comes back to the top and the last selected element is still unselect. Similarly with the opposite operation (deselect).

I searched a lot and found practically nothing. There is this group conversation that dates from 2010.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/4K1VP0h1Obk

And this previously asked question left unanswered... for 3 years.

[in IE8 using jQuery JSTree when scrolling the click handlers don't work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933122/in-ie8-using-jquery-jstree-when-scrolling-the-click-handlers-dont-work-anymore)

Anybody was stuck with such a problem? I don't get how come it's not more discussed!
Thanks guys!

EDIT: I have put the tree inside a dialog, I got this idea that the scrolling of the tree takes the height, width and coordinates from the window instead of the dialog's. Any confirmation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I discovered that not only did the tree scroll itself to the top when you try to click on a node, or even whenever you click anywhere within its bounds, but also when you press `tab`.

I soon discovered `jstree` sets a `tabindex` on the tree element, removing this fixed the problem!

```js
$('#yourtree').jstree(/*your jstree call*/).removeAttr('tabindex');
```

---

**EDIT**

I've hit this issue again when using jstree inside a [snap drawer](http://jtrussell.github.io/angular-snap.js/), on occasion when selecting nodes (and then the code focusing the browser on another element) the drawer will scroll to the top.

With the fix above, the issue only appeared on iOS safari.

However, I noticed [in chrome] that the `tabindex` is repeatedly re-set on the tree `div` whenever the user focusses on the tree (sets to `-1`) or focusses elsewhere (sets to `0`).

Hacking the javascript DoM element stopped jstree from ever manipulating the tabindex and rectified the issue completely:

```js
var tree = $('#yourtree');

tree[0].setAttribute = function(name) {
    if (name != 'tabindex')
        Element.prototype.setAttribute.apply(this, arguments);
};

$('#yourtree').jstree(/*your jstree call*/);
```